# Ошибка при установки через pip библиотеки dlib==19.18.0 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

Пишу в PyCharm в командной строке `pip install dlib==19.18.0`.
Выдает ошибку:

```
Collecting dlib==19.18.0
  Using cached dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not insta
lled.
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\andre\pycharmprojects\facerecognition\venv\scripts\p
ython.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\U
sers\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'
; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3yqhwx4
\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);co
de=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(cod
e, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\pip-record-lsxxq91w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-m
anaged --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\andre\pycharmprojects\facerecog
nition\venv\include\site\python3.8\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\dlib\
    Complete output (57 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 1
5:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-insta
ll-j3yqhwx4\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\andr
e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_
EXECUTABLE=c:\users\andre\pycharmprojects\facerecognition\venv\scripts\pytho
n.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\
Temp\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18362.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
    
    
    
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
    
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-j3yqhwx4/dlib/bu
ild/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-j3yqhwx4/dlib/bu
ild/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\dlib\setu
p.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\andre\pycharmprojects\facerecognition\venv\lib\site-pac
kages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 163, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\andre\pycharmprojects\facerecognition\venv\lib\site-pac
kages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\dis
tutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\dlib\setu
p.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\dlib\setu
p.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sub
process.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBR
ARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3y
qhwx4\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\andre\\p
ycharmprojects\\facerecognition\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRAR
Y_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-insta
ll-j3yqhwx4\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\andre\pycharmprojec
ts\facerecognition\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, t
okenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-inst
all-j3yqhwx4\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3yqhwx4\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '
"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n
'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --re
cord 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lsxxq91w\install-record.t
xt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\user
s\andre\pycharmprojects\facerecognition\venv\include\site\python3.8\dlib' Ch
eck the logs for full command output.
```

Перед этим пробовал установить через File-->Settings-->Project Interpreter

Ошибка:

```
Collecting dlib==19.18.0
  Using cached dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dv9_0huu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\include\site\python3.8\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\
    Complete output (59 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18362.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
    
    
    
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
    
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 163, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\andre\\PycharmProjects\\FaceRecognition\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dv9_0huu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\FaceRecognition\venv\include\site\python3.8\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Он при установке пытается собрать что-то из исходников, но не находит компилятор:

```
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
```

Если уже установлен MS Visual Studio, то надо запустить `Developer Command Prompt for VS` (из меню Пуск), и уже в этой консоли выполнить `pip install ...`.

Если нет компилятора, то его надо установить, и сделать доступным в процессе установки (добавить в `PATH`, или как описано выше).